# Morphism of varieties is continuous between analytic varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, hodge-theory

I'm seeking clarification on the significance of commutative diagrams in understanding the analytic topology of smooth varieties.

In Aleksander Horawa's [notes](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/horawa/math_731_Hodge.pdf), a commutative diagram is used to demonstrate that a morphism between varieties is a continuous map on the analytic topologies (Remarks $1.3$):

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
X & \overset{\text{immersion}}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb{A}^m \\
f\big\downarrow & \cdot & \big\downarrow{g} \\
Y & \underset{\text{immersion}}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb{A}^n
\end{array}
$$

However, this seems like a straightforward statement to me. We know that a morphism is a polynomial from $ \mathbb{C}^m $ to $ \mathbb{C}^n $, which has been restricted to the variety $ X $. Hence, $ f^{-1}(U \cap Y) = f^{-1}(U) \cap f^{-1}(Y) = f^{-1}(U) \cap X $, where $ U $ is an open set with respect to the Euclidean topology on $ \mathbb{C}^m $.

I'm struggling to see the significance of these statements when it comes to the analytic topology, as open sets are simply given by $ X \cap O$, where $O$ is an open set in the Euclidean topology.

Another example is Proposition $1.1$, especially ($3$). These statements appear obvious to me, and it doesn't seem like they require such elaborate proofs.

I'm very interested to know if there's something I'm missing.